# Getting metadata of all files using Dropbox Python API

Tags: python, dropbox-api

The Dropbox account I'm connected to using the Dropbox Python API has about 10k files in it's main folder. I'm interested in getting the metadata information of all files, the thing is that when I call the following:

```
client = dropbox.Dropbox('TOKEN HERE')
metadata = client.files_list_folder('').entries
fname = []
for i in metadata:
    fname.append(i)
print(len(fname))
```

It prints out only 2000 files. I find it suspicious that it only prints the info of such round number, which makes me assume that's a hard limit.

I know there's the `files_list_folder_continue` function which, if I understood correctly, continues to look for metadata where the `files_list_folder` function left off but Im not sure how to implement it. I tried the following:

```
metadata = client.files_list_folder('').entries
metadata1 = client.files_list_folder_continue('').entries
met = pd.concat([metadata, metadata1], axis=0)
```

But it produces the following error: `dropbox.stone_validators.ValidationError: '' must be at least 1 characters, got 0`. Clearly it has to do with the fact that I dont know how to use the `files_list_folder_continue` function. How can these be used?

Answer (score 2):

I realized there was a way to solve this, so I figured I post this if a beginner at python stumbles into the same doubt using python in the future:

```
metadata = client.files_list_folder('')
flist = []
if metadata.has_more == True:
    m1 = metadata.entries
    cur = metadata.cursor
    for i in m1:
        if isinstance(i, dropbox.files.FileMetadata):
            flist.append([i.name, i.size])
    m2 = client.files_list_folder_continue(cur)
    while m2.has_more == True:
        for i in m2.entries:
            if isinstance(i, dropbox.files.FileMetadata):
                flist.append([i.name, i.size])
        cur = m2.cursor
        m2 = client.files_list_folder_continue(cur)
```

That gets the name and size of all files in the home directory of the dropbox folder.

Answer (score 1):

Both answers are accurate, but only to complete Daviid's code, I'd add an `else` statement in the `while` to get the remaining files:

```
flist = []
if metadata.has_more == True:
    m1 = metadata.entries
    cur = metadata.cursor
    for i in m1:
        if isinstance(i, dropbox.files.FileMetadata):
            flist.append([i.name, i.size])
    # flist now has 2000 items
    m2 = client.files_list_folder_continue(cur)
    while m2.has_more == True:
        for i in m2.entries:
            if isinstance(i, dropbox.files.FileMetadata):
                flist.append([i.name, i.size])
        cur = m2.cursor
        m2 = client.files_list_folder_continue(cur)entries
    else:
        m_final = client.files_list_folder_continue(cur)
        for i in m_final.entries:
            if isinstance(i, dropbox.files.FileMetadata):
            flist.append([i.name, i.size])
```

That way you can retrieve all the files without breaking the loop.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that with this code you'll miss on the last iteration:
Let's say you have 11189 items. In my case files_list_folder return 2000 each time.

```
metadata = client.files_list_folder('')
flist = []
if metadata.has_more == True:
    m1 = metadata.entries
    cur = metadata.cursor
    for i in m1:
        if isinstance(i, dropbox.files.FileMetadata):
            flist.append([i.name, i.size])
    # flist now has 2000 items
    m2 = client.files_list_folder_continue(cur)
    while m2.has_more == True:
        for i in m2.entries:
            if isinstance(i, dropbox.files.FileMetadata):
                flist.append([i.name, i.size])
        cur = m2.cursor
        # 1st time : flist will have 4000 and m2.has_more==True
        # 2nd time : flist will have 6000 and m2.has_more==True
        # 3rd time : flist will have 8000 and m2.has_more==True
        # 4th time : flist will have 10000 and m2.has_more==True
        m2 = client.files_list_folder_continue(cur)
        # 5th time : m2.entries will have 1189 files but m2.has_more==False
        # so you'll step out of the loop without iterating through those 1189 entries
```

You'll need to iterate one last time through m2.entries once outside the while loop.

I know this is a year old question but I just came across this error myself.

Answer (score 0):

Paginated requests usually lend themselfs to Pythons iterators in combination with a Do-While loop (has to be simulated in Python).

1. fetch inital data
2. process data
3. If there is no more data exit
4. fetch more data with cursor
5. continue at 2.

Using an iterator allows you to start processing data without you having to wait for all paginated results to arrive.

The Do-While loop spares you code duplication and results in robust and IMHO in code much easier to follow.

```
client = dropbox.Dropbox(access_token)

def all_files_from_folder(folder):
    metadata = client.files_list_folder(folder)
    while True:
        for entry in metadata.entries:
            if isinstance(entry, dropbox.files.FileMetadata):
                yield entry
        if not metadata.has_more:
            break
        metadata = client.files_list_folder_continue(metadata.cursor)

for i in all_files_from_db_folder("/EDI/ORDERS/archive/2020"):
    print(i.path_lower)
```